# How change detail label text on UITableViewCell?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I'm just a newcomer in developing and I have problem.

In my application I have table view controller with cell (call it "Select the city"). By tapping on that cell next table view controller is opened. In the next controller I have the list of cities in my country.

And I have a question: How can I change detailLabelText by selecting one of the city?
I want to see which city I selected in this label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the value to the second page by a property declared as string in the 2nd vc and when allocing the 2nd view set the value to this property

In view controller 2 make a property of string

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * resultValue;
```

in viewdidLoad of view controller 2

```
[self. detailLabelText setText:self.resultValue];
```

When initializing 2nd View controller in didSelectRowAtIndexpath in view controller 1

```
Viewcontroller2 *val=[Viewcontroller2 alloc ]init];
val.resultValue = [datasourceArray objectAtIndex:indexpath.row];
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I wanna see the selected city at detailLabel in cell in first controller

Comment: When you select the didselect method is active and you have the selected value in hand? Pass that value to the property,dont forget to set the outlet connection in xib

Comment: In the string "[self. detailLabelText setText:self.resultValue];"  I have issue of indeclaratded identifier. Because detailLabelText is in first controller

Comment: property should be declared in ** viewcontroller 2**,You are not having 2 VC?

Comment: Yes, I have second controller. I said you, that in the string `[self. detailLabelText setText:self.resultValue];` i have the issue. And I declared property

Comment: detailLabelText is in second VC right? is it declared and outlet is set ?

Comment: detaillabelText is in first VC and it is declared and outlet is set